# Hooks in react are not updating my state correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm trying to load some data which I get from an API in a form, but I seem to be doing something wrong with my state hook.

In the code below I'm using hooks to define an employee and employeeId. 
After that I'm trying to use `useEffect` to mimic the componentDidMount function from a class component.

Once in here I check if there are params in the url and I update the employeeId state with `setEmployeeId(props.match.params.employeeId)`.

The issue is, my state value didn't update and my whole flow collapses.

Try to keep in mind that I rather use function components for this.

```
export default function EmployeeDetail(props) {
    const [employeeId, setEmployeeId] = useState<number>(-1);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [employee, setEmployee] = useState<IEmployee>();

    useEffect(() => componentDidMount(), []);

    const componentDidMount = () => {
        // --> I get the correct id from the params
        if (props.match.params && props.match.params.employeeId) { 
            setEmployeeId(props.match.params.employeeId)
        }

        // This remains -1, while it should be the params.employeeId
        if (employeeId) {
            getEmployee();
        }
    }

    const getEmployee = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        EmployeeService.getEmployee(employeeId)    // --> This will return an invalid employee
            .then((response) => setEmployee(response.data))
            .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The new value from `setEmployeeId` will be available probably in the next render. The code you're running is part of the same render so the value won't be set yet. Since you're in the same function, use the value you already have `props.match.params.employeeId`. Remember, when you call `set*` you're instructing React to queue an update. The update may happen when React decides.

Answer (score 0):

The function returned from `useEffect` will be called on onmount. Since you're using implicit return, that's what happens in your case. If you need it to be called on mount, you need to call it instead of returning.

Edit: since you also set employee id, you need to track in the dependency array. This is due to the fact that setting state is async in React and the updated state value will be available only on the next render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  componentDidMount()
}, [employeeId]);
```

An alternative would be to use the data from props directly in the `getEmployee` method:

```
useEffect(() => {
  componentDidMount()
}, []);

const componentDidMount = () => {
  if (props.match.params && props.match.params.employeeId) {
    setEmployeeId(props.match.params.employeeId)
    getEmployee(props.match.params.employeeId);
  }
}

const getEmployee = (employeeId) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  EmployeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
    .then((response) => setEmployee(response.data))
    .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but still no result. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiQUg.png

Answer (score 0):

The new value from `setEmployeeId` will be available probably in the next render.

The code you're running is part of the same render so the value won't be set yet.

Since you're in the same function, use the value you already have: `props.match.params.employeeId`.

Remember, when you call `set*` you're instructing React to queue an update. The update may happen when React decides.

If you'd prefer your `getEmployee` to only run once `currentEmployeeId` changes, consider putting that in its own effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
   getEmployee(currentEmployeeId);
}, [currentEmployeeId])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use the "updated" state before it is updated. I suggest you to use something like

```
export default function EmployeeDetail(props) {
    const [employeeId, setEmployeeId] = useState<number>(-1);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [employee, setEmployee] = useState<IEmployee>();

    useEffect(() => componentDidMount(), []);

    const componentDidMount = () => {
        // --> I get the correct id from the params
        let currentEmployeeId
        if (props.match.params && props.match.params.employeeId) { 
            currentEmployeeId = props.match.params.employeeId
            setEmployeeId(currentEmployeeId)
        }

        // This was remaining -1, because state wasn't updated
        if (currentEmployeeId) {
            getEmployee(currentEmployeeId);
            //It's a good practice to only change the value gotten from a 
            //function by changing its parameter
        }
    }

    const getEmployee = (id: number) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        EmployeeService.getEmployee(id)  
            .then((response) => setEmployee(response.data))
            .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```